# Asp.net MVC foreach loop over db only returns 1 row

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, loops, foreach

**My Controller View**

```
foreach (var dbItem in db1.Ranges.Where(x => x.DeviceId == Id).OrderByDescending(x => x.DeviceTime))
{
    list.Add((double)dbItem.Val1);
}
```

**My Database rows -->**
[Database Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDrMy.jpg)

As you can see there are alot of rows in the DB, but when i run it i only get 1 row.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but are you sure that you're quering the same DB as the screenshot? And if so, which Val1 are you getting? And are you using DevideID 162201083007044?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
var items = db1.Ranges
                 .Where(x => x.DeviceId == Id)
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.DeviceTime)
                 .Select(x => x.Val1)
                 .ToList();

// if list is a List<double>
list.AddRange(items.Select(x => (double)x));

// If you really need the foreach
foreach(var value in items)
{
    list.Add((double)value);
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate a bit why we need `items.Select(x => (double)x)` ?
I mean, I couldn't really see the difference. Just wondering if I'm missing something.

Comment: Are you pointing out the fact that I moved the cast? It's an old habit from my side. I always try to avoid too much logic in the query. But I'm sure it can be done in the query as well. Also, I added .ToList() in to query the DB before we iterate it.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I missed .ToList() was missing in OP. Nice catch!